# Sound issue with latest ubuntu release Ubuntu 23.04 on iMac

Tags: system-installation, sound, mac, 23.04

For security reasons I would like to install Ubuntu 23.04 to replace macOS.
I have a 3.1 Ghz 6-core Intel Core i5 processor, ADM Radeon Pro 5300 4GB graphics with 8GB 2667 MHz DDR4 of memory.
I recently installed Ubuntu to an older Panasonic CF-C2 laptop and had no sound after installing Ubuntu.
Upon reading some forums, I have found this is a recurring issue with Ubuntu.
Before I switch my iMac to Ubuntu, I was wondering if anyone with a similar iMac hardware configuration had sound issues after installing Ubuntu 23.04?
If so, what was the fix?
Thanking everyone in advance for any help.